# Dataframe (.csv) not entirely appending to text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, append, text-files

I'm trying to append my entire csv file into my text file, but in a way so that the information appears in lines and is separated by commas, instead of appending the spreadsheet format. My csv file (named StateChart in the code) is a spreadsheet with all 50 states, their abbreviation, their capital, their population, the number of counties, and the minimum wage. When I append it onto my text file (there is already information written on my file so I am appending the csv onto it), it is only appending the last 39 states and is not including the first 21. I have information written on the first 18 lines of the text file, so I'm not sure if this has something to do with it.

Here is my code so far:

```
def AppendFunction(StateChart):
    #Open the output.txt file and append the entire dataframe onto the file
    with open("output.txt", "a") as MyFile:
        StateChart.to_csv(MyFile, sep=',', mode='a')
```